# How to keep a DIV in a flexbox fixed in the first row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, formatting

I would like to keep a certain DIV always in the first line while others right and left from it may collapse when I am narrowing screen. Is it possible at all?

My exaple code is

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div style="background-color:#CC0000">7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

How to make the red DIV 7 to remain always in the first line?

If you have an idea, please share it with me. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use two different flex-containers, setting flex-wrap: nowrap on the first one? Or you could use css grid.

Answer (score 0):

[mediaquerie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) could help

average example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container>div {
  order: 0
}

body div.flex-container>div:nth-child(7) {
  order: 1
}

.flex-container>div:nth-child(7)~div {
  order: 2
}

@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
  .flex-container>div:nth-child(5)~div {
    order: 2
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:615px) {
  .flex-container>div:nth-child(4)~div {
    order: 2
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:515px) {
  .flex-container>div:nth-child(3)~div {
    order: 2
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:425px) {
  .flex-container>div:nth-child(2)~div {
    order: 2
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div style="background-color:#CC0000">7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>

</div>
```